# Regex: remove exact number from comma separated list in query string

Tags: regex, query-string

I'm passing a comma separated list of numbers as value in a query string. For example, I have the following query string:

```
?view=list&cat=1,8,18&sort=asc
```

Now I want to remove "8" from the "cat" variable. So far I have this, to only match the value of "cat"

```
(?<=cat=)([^&]*)
```

This will get me "1,8,18". Now I only want to select the exact digit "8", is that possible? I know it would be easier to convert the comma separated list into an array, but in this specific case that's not possible.

Edit: The regex must only match the number in the "cat" var and must work in comma separated list or as a single value. So the following test strings:

```
?view=list&cat=1,8,18&sort=asc
?view=list&cat=8&sort=asc
?view=list&cat=1,8,18&sort=asc&someOtherVar=8
```

They all must only match the single number "8" (not the last 8, because it's not preceded by "cat=")

Answer (score 1):

Without lookbehind:

```
(cat=(?:\b[^8]\d*\b)*?),?8(&)|8,
```

and replace with capturing groups 1 & 2

Now testing against your added examples above, the regex replace returns:

```
?view=list&cat=1,18&sort=asc
?view=list&cat=&sort=asc
?view=list&cat=1,18&sort=asc&someOtherVar=8
```

Comment: Well, did some more testing and found some examples where the result was incorrect -- primarily with 8's at the beginning or end of the query string.  So have modified things again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this regex:

```
(?<=cat=)(?:[^,]*,)*(8)(?:\W|$)
```

should give 8 in matched group # 1 to you.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/2tp0HiYEaY

Comment: I can't get an exact number with that regex. The one I had matches "1,8,18". I only want to match an exact number in the comma separated list. So in my example I want something that only matches "1", "8" or "18".

Comment: Will there be 3 numbers in comma separated list or it can vary?

Comment: It can vary, so if I'm looking for the exact number "8", it must also match: "?view=list&cat=8&sort=asc"

Comment: I am bit confused as the regex I provided you would give exact 8 (or whatever is there after between 1st and 2nd comma)

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear, sorry. The value in the var "cat" can vary. So in this example it's "1,8,18". But it can also have more or less numbers (separated by commas) or a single value. And I must match an exact number, for example "8"

Comment: If you already know the # you're matching `8` then you can simply use `[=,]8[,&]`. If I am still off then may be some more examples will help me understand it better.

Comment: I have updated my question with an extra example of what the regex must match. Maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Almost :) But it doesn't match 8 in the following test string: "?view=list&cat=1,2,8&sort=asc"

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure of your requirements, this regex `\bcat=(?:\d+,)*(8(?!\d),?)` will capture in group number **`1`** the number `8,` (the coma if exists) (which you can change it by a variable number).

You can test it with different input here : http://regex101.com/r/uM0bS7

It will match:

- ?view=list&cat=3,1,8,18&sort=asc
- ?view=list&cat=8,18&sort=asc
- ?view=list&cat=8&sort=asc
- ?view=list&cat=3,1,8,18,8&sort=asc
- ?view=list&cat=3,1,8&sort=asc

If you have the value `8` twice it will match the `last` one, if you want to match the `first` one you only need to make the non capturing group `(?:\d+,)*` lazy like this : `\bcat=(?:\d+,)*?(8(?!\d),?)`